# Finding values in an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, replace, find

I'm trying to find out if a value exists in an array. The following code is giving me an error each time I run saying Object has no replace method.

```
var fruits = ['apples', 'pears', 'bananas'];

console.log("Enter in a fruit name");

process.stdin.on('data', function(fruit) {

    fruit = fruit.replace("\n", "");
    if (fruits.indexOf(fruit) >= 0 ) {
        console.log("The value has been found in the array");
        process.exit(); }

    else {
        console.log("Value not found");
        process.exit(); }

});
```

At first it kept returning "Value not found" no matter what I entered, so I surmised it was the line break/enter that I press after entering my fruit. But the replace method for the fruit refuses to take. What am I missing?

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(fruit))` to see what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used the `setEncoding` method, the `data` event gets a `Buffer` object, not a string.

Use the `toString` method to decode the data in the buffer to a string:

```
var fruitName = fruit.toString().replace("\n", "");
```

It's possible that the reason that you didn't find anything in the array is that you were looking for the `Buffer` object instead of a string. In that case you might not need the `replace` after all.

Comment: Thank you!! If anyone else is interested here was the solution, cobbled together with Guffa's help:

https://gist.github.com/jennojenno/5448370